# Geometry question: equidistant center point of 45-45-90 triangle

Tags: geometry, triangles, rotations

Okay, I've been struggling on this for a couple days now. Given a 45-45-90 triangle with legs of length *n*, extend three perpendicular rays, one from each segment, such that they intersect within the body of the right triangle, and such that each is of equivalent length. What is that length?
[image]
It's empirically possible, obviously, but I can't seem to solve for x to save my life.

The intersection point represents the physical rotation point of the overall triangle, such that every face can rest flat against the X axis and that intersection point will travel only laterally, never vertically.

The closest guess I've arrived at is *n*-((*n*√2)/2), but I'll be damned if I know WHY (or even if that's actually correct); it just seems to fit a series of test inputs to an approximate degree, though I cannot prove it right. I cannot seem to find a critical length whatever approach I try.

(Forgive the crudeness of the diagram; I did that on my phone)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are constructing what is known scholastically as the [incenter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incenter) of the triangle, and $x$ is the radius of the incircle. For circumscribed polygons (which all triangles are) we have the relation $A=\frac12p r$, where $A$ is the area, $p$ is the perimeter and $r$ is the inradius. Therefore here $$\frac12 n^2=\frac{n+n+\sqrt2n}2 x\\ x=\frac{n}{2+\sqrt2}$$

Comment: Good, gods, THANK you! I was 100% certain this was an established thing, but, lacking the terms "incenter" and "inradius", you'd be astounded how hard such a thing is to google! The circular element had evaded me as well, though now you put it like that I feel stupid for not having spotted same myself (ESPECIALLY since that point is intended to be used as a 360° rotational point in the device I'm CAD-ing out!). I appreciate you showing your work as to how you arrived there, as well.

Answer (score 0):

If you construct a line from C or B to the intersection point, you will have split the space the line is in into two congruent triangles. So [image: n-1 = n]

Comment: The problem I'd been having was figuring out how to determine what that intersection point was, and how to obtain its distance from the triangle's segments. But by bisecting each angle, I can grab that center point, and from there, I can use it to scribe a circle whose radius represents *x*. I'm not sure if that the same thing you're saying.

Comment: $2(n-x)=\sqrt2 n$